# Couchbase node.js module

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am using node v.0.10.33 couchbase, node module v.2.0.0 and couchbase-server-v.3.0.1

```
   var couchbase = require("couchbase");

// Connect to Couchbase Server

var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('10.50.10.31:8091');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('beer-sample', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // Failed to make a connection to the Couchbase cluster.
    throw err;
  }

  // Retrieve a document

  bucket.get('aass_brewery-juleol', function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      // Failed to retrieve key
      throw err;
    }

    var doc = result.value;

    console.log(doc.name + ', ABV: ' + doc.abv);

    // Store a document

    doc.comment = "Random beer from Norway";

    bucket.replace('aass_brewery-juleol', doc, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        // Failed to replace key
        throw err;
      }

      console.log(result);

      // Success!
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});
```

when i run the above program on the same machine  in which couchbase server is installed its working fine..
with this line

```
 var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1:8091');
```

But when i run with another system which connected through Local area network I am getting network error. with this line

```
 var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('10.50.10.31:8091');
```

this error...

```
Couchbase Error : Network Failure
```

also tried

```
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://10.50.10.31')
```

not working...

```
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
```

working fine...

Where i am going wrong please help me...
sorry for  mistakes.

Comment: have you tried put http protocol (I placed spaces to make it visible in the comment): "http ://10.50.10.31:8091/" or "http: //10.50.10.31:8091/pools" ?

Comment: yah. i tried it . but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with python and node-gyp

i have upgraded python

and rebuild the couchbase module

```
cd path_to_nodejs_project/node_modules/coucbase/
node-gyp clean
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

As per [Couchbase Node.js SDK documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-node-1.2/), try creating connection like this:

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");

var bucket = new couchbase.Connection({
  'bucket':'beer-sample',
  'host':'10.50.10.31:8091'
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // Failed to make a connection to the Couchbase cluster.
    throw err;
  }
// your code to work with bucket here...
});
```

Comment: it seems to be an old vesion method